# Missing operand before '=' operator, when we assign RadGrid.MasterTableView.filterexpression to dataview.rowfilter in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, radgrid, dataview

RadGrid.MasterTableView.filterexpression value is "(iif(ShortDesc == null, \"\", ShortDesc).ToString().Contains(\"Co\"))" and i want to assign this value  dv.RowFilter. dv is DataView. RadGrid.MasterTableView.filterexpression value should be like (ShortDesc LIKE '%Co%') for assign but its giving me  Missing operand before '=' operator.

please tell me how to solve that error

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for this problem, we need to just set RadGrid property
EnableLinqExpressions="False"  in .aspx file. Than its auto give RadGrid.MasterTableView.filterexpression value like ShortDesc LIKE '%Co%'